# Can I use react-virtualized in server rendering

Tags: reactjs, react-virtualized, server-rendering

As title. Since it use so many factors only browsers have, I can't figure out one solution. Can anyone help me?

Comment: You should share more about what you've tried. RV is compatible with server-side rendering so far as I'm aware, although certain components (like `CellMeasurer` and `WindowScroller` will not work as they rely on the DOM).

Comment: Hi, did you find an implementation with AutoSizer and CellMeasurer? RV is compatible with server side but don't render all the nodes :(

Comment: Well, CellMeasurer and WindowScroller are components I want to use. Anyway, thanks for you answer.